# Intermediate data from MediaRecorder getting lost when using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mediastream, web-mediarecorder, mediarecorder-api

I'm working on a higher order component that will provide the ability to capture media using the MediaRecorder API.  However, when I try to use the captured video (in the form of a Blob passed to createObjectURL) I am getting an error `ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE`.  When I console log the Blob that is passed to the wrapped component, it has a length of 0.  I have included my code at the end of this post.

In order to diagnose the problem, I tried the following tests:

- Console logging newChunks in `handleDataAvailable` logs the correct value (i.e. `[Blob]`).
- I added `React.useEffect(() => console.log(chunks), [chunks]);` in order to see if chunks is actually getting updated.  This also results in the correct value being logged (i.e. `[Blob]`).
- I added `React.useEffect(() => console.log(captured), [captured]);` in order to see if captured is getting updated.  This results in a Blob of size 0 being logged.
- In `handleStop`, I console log chunks and the blob created by combining the chunks.  That results in an empty array and a blob with size 0 respectively.

This leads me to believe that `handleDataAvailable` is correctly adding each chunk to the chunks array, but somehow the array is being emptied by the time that `handleStop` gets run.

Does anyone see what might be causing that to happen?

Code:

```
import React from 'react';

import { getUserMedia, getConstraints } from '../../utils/general';

const withMediaCapture = (WrappedComponent, recordingType, facingMode, deviceID) => {
  const constraints = getConstraints(recordingType, facingMode, deviceID);

  const type = recordingType === 'audio'
    ? 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus'
    : 'video/webm; codecs=vp9';

  return props => {
    const [mediaStream, setMediaStream] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = React.useState(false);
    const [captured, setCaptured] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [chunks, setChunks] = React.useState([]);

    // On mount, get the mediaStream:
    const setupStream = () => {
      getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(setMediaStream)
      .catch(error => {/* TODO: Handle error */});
    };
    React.useEffect(setupStream, []);

    // Once we have gotten the mediaStream, get the mediaRecorder:
    const handleDataAvailable = ({ data }) => {
      const newChunks = [...chunks, data];
      setChunks(newChunks);
    };
    const handleStop = foo => {
      const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type });
      setCaptured(blob);
      setChunks([]);
    }
    const getMediaRecorder = () => {
      mediaStream && setMediaRecorder(Object.assign(
        new MediaRecorder(mediaStream),
        {
          ondataavailable: handleDataAvailable,
          onstop: handleStop,
        },
      ));
    }
    React.useEffect(getMediaRecorder, [mediaStream]);

    const toggleRecording = () => {
      isRecording
        ? mediaRecorder.stop()
        : mediaRecorder.start();
      setIsRecording(!isRecording);
    };

    return <WrappedComponent {...{ preview: mediaStream, captured, toggleRecording, isRecording, ...props }} />;
  };
};

const VideoCaptureDemo = ({ preview, captured, toggleRecording, isRecording }) => {
  const previewRef = React.useRef(null);
  const capturedRef = React.useRef(null);

  const setupPreview = () => {
    previewRef.current.srcObject = preview;
  };
  React.useEffect(setupPreview, [preview]);

  const setupCaptured = () => {
    const url = captured && window.URL.createObjectURL(captured);
    capturedRef.current.src = url;
  };
  React.useEffect(setupCaptured, [captured]);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={previewRef} autoPlay={true} muted={true} />
      <video ref={capturedRef} controls />
      <button onClick={toggleRecording}>
        {isRecording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default withMediaCapture(VideoCaptureDemo, 'videoAndAudio');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handleStop` and `handleDataAvailable` are both closing over the initial, empty `chunks` array. If `handleDataAvailable` is called more than once, earlier chunks will be lost, and `handleStop` will always create a Blob from the empty chunks array. Re-renders caused by `setChunks` will cause new versions of the `handle` methods to be created, but the MediaRecorder will still be using the versions from when the MediaRecorder was created.

You could fix `handleDataAvailable` by using [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), but in order to fix `handleStop` I think you would be best off to switch to using useReducer (with the reducer managing both `chunks` and `captured`) so that you can just dispatch an action and then the reducer can have access to the current chunks and create the Blob appropriately.

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm looking for the same exact solution. Could you post some code to illustrate the solution?